# Moving files on OpenELEC

Tags: usb, hard-drive, openelec, filesystem

I have a model B Raspberry Pi running OpenELEC v4.2.1. I have two attached usb sticks (formats: exFAT and FAT) and an attached hard drive (format: NTFS). When I go to the file manager in OpenELEC I can rename and delete files on both usb sticks but I cannot do the same on the hard drive.

Do I need to format my hard drive to exFAT or FAT to be able to rename and delete files stored on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I formatted the hard drive to ext4. Now I can rename, delete and copy files between all the peripherals.